# A inverse Trigonometric multiple Integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, closed-form

How to calculate the closed form of the integral
$$\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{\int\limits_0^x {{{\left( {\arctan t} \right)}^2}dt} }}{{x\left( {1 + {x^2}} \right)}}} dx$$

Comment: What is the motivation? Do you know if it has a closed form or just wondering? Personally, I would rather not waste time on such a problem if it is just taken out of the hat (implying that an analytic solution is not likely to exist) so it would be nice if you could clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Use integration by parts, taking $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x} (\arctan t)^2 dt$  as the first function and $ \dfrac{1}{x(x^2+1)} $ as the second function to get:

$ \displaystyle \int \dfrac{dx}{x(x^2+1)} = \dfrac{1}{2} \ln\bigg(\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+1}\bigg)$

Hence,

$I = \bigg|\dfrac{1}{2} \ln \bigg(\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+1}\bigg) \displaystyle \int_{0}^{x} (\arctan t)^2 dt \bigg|_{0}^{1} - \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}
 \dfrac{1}{2} \ln \bigg(\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+1}\bigg)  (\arctan x)^2 dx  $

= $ \displaystyle \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}  (\arctan x)^2 \ln\bigg(\dfrac{1+x^2}{2x^2}\bigg) dx $

I am not able to solve it further

Comment: Mathematica is unable to give any closed form for it